# Why model contains old data in DB after reload?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

Should not before(:all) be executed only once? In my example the bottom test fails, because db record contains old data (name == "John"). Why so? I changed it in test above it to "Irow".

```
describe "Widget" do
before(:all) do
  @widget = Widget.create(name: "John")
end

it "changes Widget's #name in DB" do
  expect do
    @widget.name = "Irow"
    @widget.save!
  end.to change { @widget.reload.name}.from("John").to("Irow")
end

it "#name must be updated in DB by previous test" do
  expect(@widget.reload.name).to eq("Irow") # failing test
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that either in your `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper.rb` there is a line `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`.

What your tests are doing is running each test in a dedicated transaction and rolling back said transaction after the test is finished.

Your first test will change the `@widget` name to `Irow`, pass successfully and rollback the changes to the database.

This puts you in a state where after this test

```
@widget.name == "Irow"
```

but

```
@widget.reload.name == "John"
```

as the transaction which changed the name to `Irow` was rolled back, so the row in database has `John` again.

The other thing worth mentioning is that you might be running your tests in a random order (`config.order = :random`), thus your tests would be blinking if you were not running each test in a dedicated transaction.

Try to make your tests as isolated as possible, use `before(:all)` only if it **really** makes sense (perhaps for some really expensive operations).